# SharePoint Online Permissions Not Updating

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, active-directory

Some of our SharePoint sites have permissions maintained in AD.  I added a person to a group in question, but he can not yet access the site.  The change was made two days ago.  If I pull up the Microsoft 365 admin center I can see that the AD group has synced and he is a member of it, yet he still does not have access to the site.  If I look at permissions of other members of the AD group on the site I do see them as having access through that group.  Am I missing a step, or is there an automated process that takes place that refreshes SharePoint permissions?  If so, can that be adjusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is knowing isssue with Active Directory groups... It takes some time to apply new permissions... Sometimes it is few hours, sometimes few days (we already faced this issue)

1. If you sync AD to AAD, check if there are errors in synchronization > do full sync to AAD
2. Verify that user in Office 365 portal in Users has right groups
3. AAD and SP User Service have own jobs for synchronization and it run automatically, you must wait. **If you need permissions now, set account to SharePoint group**